# Footer floating in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to coding and am making my first site on WP. I have been bludgeoning WP into submission using the HTML 5 Blank template.  I am having trouble getting my footer to stay at the bottom of the page rather than floating in the middle at times.  I understand how to do this on my end, however when I do it in WordPress weird things happen.

When I make my html height:100% in css or when I make my body position:absolute;  all my content moves down the page by about the length of a page.  I have been trying to band-aid it for each individual page but it creates more and more problems.  Anyone got ideas?

[the site](http://joebiz.net/blog) (it's under a random directory so that I can build it while it's not completely live).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You HAVE TO SET height on html and body and then on footer set position absolute. Use below css

```
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; height:100%;}
footer{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;}
```

Comment: I tried this and it gets the footer so where I want it but something weird has happened between my wordpress theme and my stuff I've created within it.  I built it locally and everything looked perfect the way I want it.  Now in wordpress when I apply this weird gaps appear in the page, so I have to adjust things up with -margins.  There must be something displaying that I am not getting with WP.

Comment: OK try this .container {
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;}     footer { background: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;}

Comment: In this page http://joebiz.net/blog/category/blog/ footer inside class="container" but other pages footer outside class="container" like http://joebiz.net/blog/ at first solve that problem.

Comment: That only fixed the pages with his resume on it.  The rest of the pages it floats to the middle of the page or completely to the top.

Comment: yes on resume page http://joebiz.net/blog/resume/ footer outside class="container" so this working. you have to set other pages same as this structure.

Comment: Okay so It seems like I am on a good track on everything now BUT the resume pages.  I have tried to do them similarly to the rest of the pages, but it is still displaying in the middle of the resume.

Comment: Can you send me your update sample? Do you used my last css that I suggested? .container { height: auto !important; height: 100%;} footer { background: #333333; width: 100%; height: 60px; bottom: 0;}

Comment: I can see in footer     position: absolute; remove that.

Comment: Okay so deleting that made all the other pages not work.  So I kept it and used a body class for the footer on the resume pages and used position:static;  That fixed it.  Thank you SO MUCH for your time on this.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a million. You saved me lots of time.

Answer (score -2):

Use `overflow:hidden;` for `footer` upper `div`.

Comment: Which upper div are you referring to?